# How to get the call `authorize_upgrade` from `cumulus_pallet_parachain_system` inside another pallet?

Tags: extrinsic, cumulus, upgrade, configuration, config

I would like to schedule the dispatch call `authorize_upgrade` inside a custom pallet. For this I need the call enum variant of the `cumulus_pallet_parachain_system` pallet. How can I get this? Via the config parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::Call::<T>::authorize_upgrade { code_hash }
```

This gives you access in your pallet to the parachain system `Call`. `T` needs to implement `cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::Config`.

In your config you need to add:

```
trait Config {
... 
    type Call: From<cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::Call> + frame_support::dispatch::Dispatchable;
... 
}
```

This is required to be able to convert the parachain system call into the runtime call and to dispatch the call.

Comment: Do I need to tightly couple `cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::Config` to my pallet? Do you have an example? I can't get it working. How to call the `authorize_upgrade` with your Call parameter inside my pallet. How to set the config parameter in the runtime?

Comment: Got it with your help. It is exactly as you described, but I didn't know that I can just pass in the whole `Call` struct of the runtime (`type Call = Call;`). I tightly coupled it with `+ cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::Config`. Thanks a lot Bastian!

Comment: Good to hear that you made it :)